# Windows workflow 4.0 stops working

Tags: asp.net, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I have created one long running workflow in asp.net 4.0.

[image]

This WF start once & never stop. I have start this workflow from my web application.
In Global.asax,

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  var LicClient = new WFService.LicWFClient();
  LicClient.StartWorkFlow();
}
```

I have used some code activity for database transactions.

Process Replenishment - Check requests which are hold due to some reason then process to check it for full fill there requirements & if it valid then pass to next, other wise hold again. Send notification mail about it.

LicenseRequest - Check for valid request.

Sleep 30 Sec - Thread sleep for 30 sec.

Process on Request - Process on request & send notification mail about it.

Sleep 1 Min - Thread sleep for 1 min.

It works fine for me but on server getting me some issues.

1. Work Flow stops after some time

   - this is not happen daily. So we start it manually.
2. Error :

   The context is not currently tracking the entity. Parameter name: entity at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.UpdateObject(Object entity) at LicenseWF.SaveLicenseData.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)

   - this happens with valid request but not all, getting one in 2 days.

If any idea, please suggest me.
thanks in advance...

Comment: It seems a problem on your SaveLicenseData activity. More specifically something related with your Data service not being able to commit when you call `Update`. Workflow is stopping because the exception is not handled property, but it doesn't seem anything directly related to the workflow itself.

Comment: yes, error comes on Update call but it update given entity after throwing error means it automatically repeat Update call & commit successfully. I have catch this exception very carefully so no chance to stop workflow for this reason.